# Mixed ascii and unicode output from script - how to get command to output all as ascii?

Tags: unicode, cmd, windows-7, ascii

I have a script which is run from a service which is built using C++ and is not built using unicode.  This program runs the script below and strangely, the output from the script running the wmic qfe list line seems to output as unicode.  Sample output below.

Here is the script:

```
@echo off
echo This text is output as standard - no spacing between characters >>C:\log.txt

REM this one is output with 1 space between characters
wmic qfe list >>C:\log.txt

echo This text is also output as standard - no spacing >>C:\log.txt
```

Sample output

```
This text is output as standard - no spacing between characters
C a p t i o n                                                                                 C S N a m e                 D e s c r i p t i o n             F i x C o m m e n t s     H o t F i x I D       I n s t a l l D a t e     I n s t a l l e d B y                                   I n s t a l l e d O n     N a m e     S e r v i c e P a c k I n E f f e c t     S t a t u s     

h t t p : / / s u p p o r t . m i c r o s o f t . c o m / ? k b i d = 4 0 1 2 2 1 2           M F M - 7 4 2 - 0 - 7 1     S e c u r i t y   U p d a t e                               K B 4 0 1 2 2 1 2                               N T   A U T H O R I T Y \ S Y S T E M                   5 / 1 8 / 2 0 1 7                   

This text is also output as standard - no spacing
```

Actually, I just viewed the file using a hex editor and the characters between the letters are null characters.  so presumably wmic qfe list must be outputting unicode.

So how do I either get it all output as ascii or all output as unicode.  Everything output as ascii would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wmic qfe list | find /v "" >> c:\log.txt
wmic qfe list | findstr "^" >> c:\log.txt
```

Pipe the output of the `wmic` command to a `find` or `findstr` command (you can also use `sort` if you don't have problems with the order, or `more` if your output has less than 65535 lines) before redirecting the output to the file.

Comment: How does that work?  Is it because find can read unicode AND ascii but only outputs ascii?

Comment: @AngusComber, I don't have a debugger at hand at this moment to be 100% sure, so this is just a guess. I have tested this approach with more *filter*  applications and the behaviour is consistent, so, it is not the command used who deals with the unicode, it is `wmic` who adapts its output depending on the type of the ouput stream.