# Remove unwanted spaces in wmic results through batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

Im working on a batch file in which I need to show the estimated charge remaining of the battery, I have achieved my goal but sadly I am not happy with the results due to excesive and unwanted spaces in the command result.

Here's my code:

```bat
:charge
FOR /F "delims= skip=1" %%i IN ('WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining') DO ( SET CHR=%%i
GOTO results )

:results
ECHO "Battery Percentage: %CHR%"
PAUSE
GOTO menu
```

The result of the above command is: `"Battery Percentage: 100           "`

How do I get rid of those spaces at the end of the result?

Thanks in advance and any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `... DO ( SET /a CHR=%%I` (also removes that ugly and disturbing `CR`)

Comment: I'd use `for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('wmic path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining') do for /F %%J in ("%%I") do set "CHR=%%i"` in order to avoid the trailing spaces and conversion problems from Unicode to ANSI, hence no `goto :results` is necessary anymore. This is a more generic solution not just working for integer values...

Comment: @Stephan your awnser was exactly what i needed, thanks i do not know how to close this question from your awnser but this solved my issue

Comment: keep in mind, that is a very simple solution, working only for Integer output. In general, the suggestion from aschipfl is better.

Comment: @aschipfl yesterday I "borrowed" some code from you to complete my answer. Feel free to convert your comment to an answer and add my simplified solution as "especially for this case".

Comment: [Combine Batch/WMIC + ANSI/UNICODE Output formatting](https://superuser.com/q/812438/241386), [Editing WMIC output format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19462042/995714), [Mixed ascii and unicode output from script - how to get command to output all as ascii?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44065913/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixed ascii and unicode output from script - how to get command to output all as ascii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065913/mixed-ascii-and-unicode-output-from-script-how-to-get-command-to-output-all-as)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this:

```
:charge
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i IN ('WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining /format:value') DO (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%i") do set "%%#"
)
echo %EstimatedChargeRemaining%
```

WMIC adds additional  character but it can be removed with one more for loop -> https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266

Comment: One more wonderful working solution for this issue in addition to the solutions posted on additional question [Why is the error message “Missing operand” output on processing WMIC output and assigning a value to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546076/) of original poster of this question.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand why you ask basically the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53546076) twice...

Anyway, to keep the long story short: `wmic` returns Unicode text, while `for /F` is made for ASCII/ANSI text. `for /F` converts the Unicode text to ANSI, but leaves conversion artefacts like orphaned carriage-return characters behind. These are the reason why there seems to be output empty lines past the (last) data line. The trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> are not conversion artefacts though, they are really output by the `wmic` command.

For instance, the command line:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic Path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining') do echo/%%I
```

...outputs something like the following text (`{CR}` stands for a carriage-return character and `{SPACE}` for a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>):

> ```cmd
> EstimatedChargeRemaining{SPACE}{SPACE}{CR}
> 100{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{CR}
> {CR}
> ```

Wrapping around another `for /F` loop removes those carriage-return characters, so the command line:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic Path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ("%%I") do echo/%%J
)
```

...would output something like this:

> ```cmd
> EstimatedChargeRemaining{SPACE}{SPACE}
> 100{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}
> ```

As you can see, the carriage-return characters disappear, and so does the very last line (which you skip over by the `goto return` command in your code). Any trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> are still there though. However, such can be gotten rid of by adapting the `tokens` and `delims` options of `for /F` adequately:

```cmd
rem // Skip the header line by `skip` option in the outer loop; do not tokenise anything here:
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%I in ('wmic Path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining') do (
    rem /* Tokenise the output as needed in the inner loop;
    rem    remember that `tokens` defaults to `1` and `delims` defaults to SPACE and TAB: */
    for /F %%J in ("%%I") do echo/%%J
)
```

The output is going to be something like (without any trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> this time):

> ```cmd
> 100
> ```

---

An even better way, particularly when the data returned by `wmic` might contain <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> on their own, is to change the output format of the `wmic` command using the `/VALUE` option, which does not produce trailing spaces.

For instance, the command line:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic Path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining /VALUE') do echo/%%I
```

...outputs something like the following text (`{CR}` stands for a carriage-return character):

> ```cmd
> {CR}
> {CR}
> EstimatedChargeRemaining=100{CR}
> {CR}
> {CR}
> {CR}
> ```

Again wrapping around another `for /F` loop removes those carriage-return characters, so the command line:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic Path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining /VALUE') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ("%%I") do echo/%%J
)
```

...would output something like this:

> ```cmd
> EstimatedChargeRemaining=100
> ```

Also here, the carriage-return characters disappear, and so do all the lines that just contain one such character. Note that there are no trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> at all. Now you just have to split off the name of the value:

```cmd
rem // Do not tokenise anything in the outer loop:
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic Path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining /VALUE') do (
    rem /* Tokenise the output as needed in the inner loop: */
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do echo/%%K
)
```

The output is going to be something like:

> ```cmd
> 100
> ```

This method failed in case the value began with an equal-to sign though. To handle such properly, you could do this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic Path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining /VALUE') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        rem // Store whole line in a variable:
        set "VALUE=%%K"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Split off value name:
        set "VALUE=!VALUE:*EstimatedChargeRemaining=!"
        rem // Split off leading `=`:
        echo(!VALUE:~1!
        endlocal
    )
)
```