# For loop not working properly in batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, wmic

I am trying to get the current operating system using this batch file. It is:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ('wmic path win32_operatingsystem get caption') do set _os=%%a %%b %%c %%d
echo You are running %_os%.
goto :eof
```

My operating system is windows 7 so I expected it will return:

```
You are running Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate.
```

But it returns you are running %c %d.

```
Why I am getting this result?
```

Comment: See [Why is the error message “Missing operand” output on processing WMIC output and assigning a value to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546076/) And there are only the loop variables `a` and `b` because of `tokens=1*`. I suggest `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_operatingsystem get caption /Value') do set "_os=%%I"`

Comment: You are specifying two tokens (`1` and `*`) but you gave four `for` variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways, one already posted by [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) in the above comment which already demonstrates the main change using `/value`. You can also use the caption itself as variable name with its value:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic path win32_operatingsystem get caption /value') do set %%a>nul 2>&1
echo %caption%
```